# How to declare services in symfony 4 when a class can have multiple definitions

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

So basically, if you want to upgrade to symfony 4 you can no longer have services declared like:

```
services:
    some.service:
        class: AppBundle\SomeService
        ...
```

You must change that to:

```
services:
    AppBundle\SomeService:
        ...
```

But what happens when you have multiple definitions for the same class? For example:

```
services:
    some.service1:
        class: AppBundle\SomeService
        ...
    some.service2:
        class: AppBundle\SomeService
        ...
    some.service3:
        class: AppBundle\SomeService
        ...
```

They all use the same class called SomeService, but they have different configurations, so depending on your need you can call either some.service1, some.service2 or some.service3. Now, how will that services.yml file be changed to respect symfony 4 standards? Because if you do something like:

```
services:
    AppBundle\SomeService:
        ...
    AppBundle\SomeService:
        ...
    AppBundle\SomeService:
        ...
```

It will just override your previous declarations and only keep the last one.

Any solution?

Comment: You still can use alias for [services definition](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#service-autowiring-alias)...

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding a few things.  You can indeed still define services per your first example.  Using the class name as the service id allows autowire to do it's magic.  But if you do have more then one implementation per class then old style service ids are fine and you just need to manually wire them when injecting.

Comment: @Cerad your comment should be an answer IMHO

Comment: A bit off topic but in many cases when you have multiple services for one class then it might be better to make a SomeServiceFactory class and inject it.  Just depends on the use case.